# What's a great program for creating visual software mockups?

Tags: mockups

I have a presentation due in about three hours and rather than handing in something I drew in pencil, I'd rather turn in something nicer to the client.

Is there something out there that lets me pick and drag common controls to create mockups?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web UI prototyping tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/720191/web-ui-prototyping-tools)

Comment: how is this a dup if he's not asking about web in particular?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156755/tools-for-creating-ui-prototype

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tools for creating UI prototype.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156755/tools-for-creating-ui-prototype)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

balsamiq

http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups

Answer (score 5):

[Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups), hands down.

Answer (score 1):

Visio isn't bad if your willing to pay for something. It comes with widgets that resemble actual windows components.
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/fx100487861033.aspx

Comment: I forgot to mention that I found a set of 'sketch' shapes for Visio that make it look like the design was drawn in pencil. I found this really useful because anyone collaborating on the mockup could see from the graphics it wasn't screenshots of a built UI. I think it made people more willing to comment since they didn't feel like they were suggesting a change to something that was already done. I think if you googled 'sketch visio gui shapes' you would probably find them.